# Using AsyncTask as an inner class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have created a pedometer application which works fine as an independent application. I thought I can use it in another application I have and hence came to know about AsyncTask class to do the same. I read about the syntax of AsyncTask and pasted the pedometer code in it accordingly but it's giving me errors that I  am not able to fix. So I just created a new project and pasted the AsyncTask code there to find where exactly I am wrong but I am getting no where. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.momo.background;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

public TextView count;
public TextView mod;
public TextView cTime;
public TextView pTime;
public TextView timeDiff;
public TextView stepSpeed;
public SensorManager sensorManager;

public float speed;
float fin, initial, tdiff, sSpeed;
public SensorEvent event;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new backgroundtask().execute();


}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if (countSensor != null) {

        sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI); // original
        new backgroundtask().execute();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "count sensor not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //toast prints the message
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

class backgroundtask extends AsyncTask<Void, Float, Float> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected Float doInBackground(Void... params) {


        fin = initial / 1000000000;
        initial = event.timestamp;
        tdiff = initial / 1000000000 - fin;
        sSpeed = 1 /tdiff;
        speed = sSpeed;
        publishProgress(speed);
        return speed;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {
        pTime.setText(String.valueOf(fin));
        cTime.setText(String.valueOf(initial / 1000000000));
        count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0])); // normal pedometer
        mod.setText(String.valueOf((initial / 1000000000) % 5));
        timeDiff.setText(String.valueOf(tdiff));
        stepSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(values));
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is missing an initialization of everything, from TextViews that are supposed to display the results, to SensorManager instance. That's why your code will get a plenty of NullPointerExceptions. Make sure you assign references to you instance variables in order to access the actual objects (TextViews, etc).

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

your implementation of the Async Class is not correct as I understand it.
also it may help is you showed us a stack trace or explained the errors
move the code from the

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Float... values) {

}
```

to

```
protected void onPostExecute(Float speed)
{
    pTime.setText(String.valueOf(fin));
    cTime.setText(String.valueOf(initial / 1000000000));
    count.setText(String.valueOf(event.values[0])); // normal pedometer
    mod.setText(String.valueOf((initial / 1000000000) % 5));
    timeDiff.setText(String.valueOf(tdiff));
    stepSpeed.setText(String.valueOf(speed));
}
```

as everytime the onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)method is called it will create a new AsyncTask.